# K8ssandra/cass-management-api image pull error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, k8ssandra

I am following [Single Cluster Installation](https://docs-v2.k8ssandra.io/install/local/single-cluster-helm/) on my dev environment.

`kubectl get pods -n k8ssandra-operator` gives below output -

```
NAME                                               READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
demo-dc1-default-sts-0                             1/2     ErrImagePull       0          81m
demo-dc1-default-sts-1                             1/2     ImagePullBackOff   0          81m
demo-dc1-default-sts-2                             1/2     ImagePullBackOff   0          81m
k8ssandra-operator-7568db8d8f-7l6vb                1/1     Running            0          84m
k8ssandra-operator-cass-operator-f6df9b874-gmsbp   1/1     Running            0          84m
```

`kubectl describe pod demo-dc1-default-sts-1 -n k8ssandra-operator` output is as below -

```
Warning Failed 101s (x8 over 65m) kubelet Failed to pull image "k8ssandra/cass-management-api:4.0.1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/k8ssandra/cass-management-api:4.0.1": failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open: server message: invalid_token: authorization failed
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add docker credentials as secret and then add it in the manifest file